# What is the difference between Dim, Global, Public, and Private as Modular Field Access Modifiers?

Tags: vba, vb6, scope, access-modifiers

In VB6/VBA, you can declare module-level variables outside of a specific `Sub` or `Function` method.  I've used `Private` and `Public` before inside modules and understand them like so:

- `Public` - visible to all code inside the module and all code outside the module, essentially making it global.
- `Private` - visible only to code inside the module.

I've noticed that you can use `Dim` and `Global` as modifiers for modular variables.  Are `Dim` and `Global` different from `Private` and `Public`, respectively, when used as access modifiers on modular fields? If so, how are they different?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

`Dim` and `Private` work the same, though the common convention is to use `Private` at the module level, and `Dim` at the Sub/Function level. `Public` and `Global` are nearly identical in their function, however `Global` can only be used in standard modules, whereas `Public` can be used in all contexts (modules, classes, controls, forms etc.) `Global` comes from older versions of VB and was likely kept for backwards compatibility, but has been wholly superseded by `Public`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Your explanation is pretty much what I had been thinking.  I'm starting at a huge block of legacy code that has all four modifiers used in the declarations sections of a single module.

Comment: Global variables keep theit value after execution.

Comment: Comparing your comments against the online help for Excel 2010 reveals a couple of very fine points: "Variables declared using the Public statement are available to all procedures in all modules in all applications unless Option Private Module is in effect; in which case, the variables are public only within the project in which they reside.

Moreover, caution: The Public statement can't be used in a class module to declare a fixed-length string variable.  
Since both of the above are obscure use cases, neither is likely to be a practical concern. Nevertheless, in the interest of completeness.

Comment: Although the question only concerned module-level declarations, for the sake of completeness (and for newbies) it's worth mentioning explicitly that `Private` and `Public` are not even allowed inside procedures. The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/private-statement) of the `Private` statement seems to have a typo in this regard (it's almost identical to and probably(?) copied from the documentation for the `Dim` statement): " When you use the Private statement in [sic!] a procedure..."

Comment: Is there documentation of the deprecation of `global` in favor of `public`?