# Excel: do all the models in a workbook share all the global variables?

Tags: excel, vba, scope

I tried looking for the answer for this question, but go no where. So I understand if I declare a variable outside a sub/function, it's accessible to all the subs/functions with in that module. What about other modules? Do I have to declare it? Or can I use it without declaring it?

For example, I have a textstream object that's used for logging in multiple modules. Basically what I want do is to initialize them once and all the functions in my modules can use the same objTF object to write to a log file. These objects are initialized in a commandbutton_click event. But where do I declare them?

```
Dim objFSO As FileSystemObject
Dim objTF As TextStream
```

Do I have to put them at the beginning in all of the modules? Or only one of the modules is enough? What is the correct way to do it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

try this (outside of a sub or function):

```
Public objFSO As FileSystemObject
Public objTF As TextStream
```

that should declare them globally so that they are accessible from any module in the project.

edit:

there's a good explanation of vba variable scoping in the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815547/what-is-the-difference-between-dim-global-public-and-private-as-modular-field).