# CommandButton_Click doesn't remember my variable VBA EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba

I am making a userform for making a order in a pub for example.

So my intention is whenever I click on a commandbutton, it has to appear in my listbox.
SO when I click on Cola

There will be in my listbox: Cola    1

The next time I click on cola, there should be Cola   2
but that doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


With Sheets(3)
        .Cells(Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex + 2, 2) = .Cells(Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex + 2, 2) + 1
End With



Dim i As Integer
i = 1
With Me.ListBox1
    Me.ListBox1.ColumnCount = 2
    Me.ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "60;60"
    .AddItem
    .List(0, 0) = CommandButton1.Caption
    .List(0, 1) = i
End With

   i = i + 1


End Sub
```

But he doesn't seem to remember the value of i
And so when I click a second time on Cola, nothing changes.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i` is a procedure level variable - it only persists until the procedure runs its course. When `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()` ends then `i` effectively ceases to exist.

Declare `i` in a module as `Global`

`Global i as Long 'Long doesn't have much more overhead than Integer`

and it will persist after your code runs

You also need to loose the

`Dim i As Integer
i = 1`

because that is resetting `i` every time you click the button.

Comment: `Global` is [old an unnecessary](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3815797/11683). Promoting a local variable to a broader scope is also bad. The correct thing is to declare the variable inside the procedure as `Static`.