# Having a public variable available in userform / sheet objects

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I've spent the last hour reading pages about variable scope in various flavours of excel vba, and could not find a definite documentation reference addressing my scope problem... even though i'm convinced it is such a classic. Oh well, here goes.

I've got a workbook that contains just one sheet and one userform. I have a list of students sitting in column 1 on my sheet. I would like to :

- load this list up into some global Collection variable named `students_list` (i do this using a Workbook-Open() procedure in the **ThisWorkbook** object)
- use the contents of `students_list` to initialize a listbox in my userform
- remove elements from `students_list` when a button on my userform is clicked on

All i need is a variable that is seen from within my userform's procedures, as well as from inside the **ThisWorkbook** object.

I tried declaring it as public, global, in the sheet's code, in the userform, in ThisWorkbook, in a separate module dedicated to globals... I just can't seem to find the right way to have the `students_list` variable visible from everywhere.

What am I missing ? My apologies for this question that should be so basic and yet beats me :-/

Comment: You could use a `Range` of the spreadsheet to store the list and be accessible by all the different elements of your VBA code -- essentially from any sheet and any module. If you don't want this scratch area to be visible, start it out in column BB and/or set the font color to white so a user won't notice it.

Comment: If you declared `students_list` as `Public` in a module, the variable **should** have been available to all procedures within the project. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3815797/6535336.  (The only exception would be if you declared another variable with the same name in some other place - then that second variable would be being referred to within the scope of the second declaration.)

Comment: No pb with having the scratch area visible, actually that's the way I load up values into my `students_list` collection... but that's not the issue here i'm afraid.

Comment: @YowE3K: yes, like you said, it should have been :)  

I've tried testing with minimal amount of code :  
* in the ThisWorkbook code, just the one line : `Public foo As Integer`

* in sheet1's code :  
`Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
foo = 4
MsgBox "foo set to 4"
End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
MsgBox "foo = " & foo
End Sub`

Comment: Ok, sorry for the comment layout, can't seem to make lists or line breaks work ok in comments.  

Anyway, I just wanted to add that I do not get the expected message "foo = 4". Now please yell at me and point me to my obvious mistakes.

Comment: I have added an answer but, in short, a variable within an Object has to be referred to with Object.Variable syntax if being accessed from outside the Object, but a variable within a Module can be referred to by just the variable name.

Answer (score 4):

Place the declaration of your `Public` variables inside a Module (use Insert / Module from the menu to create one, if you don't already have one).  The scope will then extend to your whole project.

So in a Module (e.g. Module1) have:

```
Public foo As Integer
```

And in the worksheet (e.g. Sheet1) code have:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    foo = 4
    MsgBox "foo set to 4"
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox "foo = " & foo
End Sub
```

---

If you were to place the declaration in the code for `ThisWorkbook` you would need to reference it as `Thisworkbook.foo` because, although it is accessible from any part of the code, it is a variable specific to that `ThisWorkbook` object.

So, in the code for ThisWorkbook have:

```
Public foo As Integer
```

And in the worksheet (e.g. Sheet1) code have:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    ThisWorkbook.foo = 4
    MsgBox "foo set to 4"
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox "foo = " & ThisWorkbook.foo
End Sub
```