# Using Public Variables in VBA for excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a program where when the workbook opens, it shows a userform. This userform collects data that I will use to put in a table. I aslo use this data to derive a file name. Everytime sheet 1 is edited I want to save the file as the file name generated from the user form. I am having trouble becuase the file name that is generated in "ThisWorkbook" is not passing to the Worksheet_Change sub in Sheet1. I also put in an if statement that I thought would top the sub from working on sheet2 but that is not working either.

Here is the code from "ThisWorkbook"

```
Option Explicit

Public SavePath As String
Public FileName As String
Public LotNumber As String
Public day As String
Public PartNumber As String
Public shift As String


Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Worksheets("template").Activate 'activates template worksheet if others are open

Worksheets("template").Protect Password:="Bard", UserInterfaceOnly:=True 'protects book for vba modifications only

UserForm1.Show

LotNumber = Worksheets("data").Range("A3").Value 'Lot number from data sheet

day = Format(Date, "mm.dd.yy") 'format current date

PartNumber = Worksheets("Data").Range("B3").Value 'takes part number from data sheet

shift = Worksheets("Data").Range("c3").Value 'takes shift from data sheet

FileName = LotNumber & " " & day & " " & PartNumber & " " & shift 'file name string with lot number, date, and part number

SavePath = "C:\Users\lnieman\Desktop\Bard Echo PS Data Collection\" & FileName 'sets saving path location on desktop


End Sub
```

And Here is from Sheet1:

```
Option Explicit




Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)

Dim WatchRange As Range
Dim WorkSheetTemplate As Worksheet


Set WorkSheetTemplate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")

If Me.Name = WorkSheetTemplate.Name Then
Set WatchRange = Me.Range("B3, D3, F3")

If Not Intersect(target, WatchRange) Is Nothing Then
Exit Sub
End If

'SavePath = ThisWorkbook.SavePath

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  MsgBox "SavePath: " & SavePath

    ' Debugging information
    Debug.Print "SavePath before SaveAs: " & SavePath

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=SavePath & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled 'saves copy with path name and as macro enabled

 ' Debugging information
    Debug.Print "SavePath after SaveAs: " & SavePath

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If

End Sub
```

I tried adding in some msgbox and debig.print but the msgbox is blankand the debug is not doing anything.

Comment: Public variables have to be declared in a Module.

Comment: You can also specify the object that the declaration is in, i.e. filling your value in the workbook_open and calling it in sheet1 as `ThisWorkbook.SavePath`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40073952/having-a-public-variable-available-in-userform-sheet-objects) that explains it more.

Comment: Using `Option Explicit` will give you a compile-time warning that those variables in `ThisWorkbook` can't be seen by your code in Sheet1