# Calling set of event functions of objects in other sub function

Tags: vba, excel

I have an UserForm in Excel VBA with different Objects like CheckBox, RadioButtons, TextEdit Box etc. Each Object has different event functions, but i want to call the some event functions in user defined sub function like UserForm_Init() function in order to re-utilize the same code written in them.

Example:

```
Private Sub  CheckBox1_Click() [Later changed to public also]
    If CheckBox1.Value Then
         --- Code
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub    CheckBox2_Click()
      If CheckBox2.Value Then
         --- Code
      End If
End Sub

Private Sub    RadioButton1_Click()
    If RadioButton1.Value Then
         --- Code
    End If
End Sub

' User Defined Function
Sub UserForm_Init()
     CheckBox1_Click()
     CheckBox2_Click()
     RadioButton1_Click()
End Sub
```

But when i am trying to compile it is showing compile error, how can i execute these object event functions within user-defined sub function.

I know I can write individual functions within Event functions and call these individual functions for user-defined sub function. But in this case, it will be too-difficult to re-change entire code. I have only option of calling these event-functions in an sub-function for execution.

How can i perform these actions, call event functions with in the user defined sub function [UserForm_Init()]?

Comment: **Your code is not VBA**, and it's hard to determine what you're trying to do without a clear picture.  (See "[mcve]".)  For now, see [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=private+public+declaration+vba) as well as [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3815547/8112776).

Comment: @ashleedawg I have already written code for CheckBox and Radio buttons when i have checked or Enabled. So, next time when i opening the same userform, i want to run the same code, so i want to do that by calling the event functions directly. Which i am not able to do that and showing compile error.

Comment: As stated in my answer, the correct way to do it is to put shared code in a shared module.  I understand your code is written *may* require some changes, but it's part of the learning process.

Comment: @ashleedwag I am sorry, I have uploaded code in C - format. I have corrected the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBA doesn't use curly braces. This code won't compile with those. VBA requires `Sub` and `End Sub` to define the procedures.

```
Sub CheckBox1_Click()

  if CheckBox1.Value Then
     --- Code
  end if
End Sub

Sub CheckBox2_Click()

  if CheckBox2.Value Then
     --- Code
  end if
End Sub

Sub RadioButton1_Click()

  if RadioButton1.Value Then
     --- Code
  End If
End Sub


Sub UserForm_Init()
 CheckBox1_Click()
 CheckBox2_Click()
 RadioButton1_Click()
End Sub
```

**NOTE:** If your custom function `UserForm_Init` is not in the Form's code module, you'll need to qualify the procedure names, e.g.:

```
Sub UserForm_Init()
 UserForm1.CheckBox1_Click()
 UserForm1.CheckBox2_Click()
 UserForm1.RadioButton1_Click()
End Sub
```

Additional complexity may arise based on your implementation, but I hope this will get you started.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I have forget to call the event functions by UserForm1.EventFunction(). Making the Event Functions Public is also important to call the functions in other functions.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing parts of code in your example; it's hard to determine what you're trying to do without a clear picture.   It is possible to call an event procedure from another, it's a bad idea for a number of reasons.

Instead of calling a private procedure like you're trying to, sort of like this:

```
Private Sub myEvent()
    'event code here
End Sub

Sub mySub()
    myEvent()
End Sub
```

...you're better off to move the code that you need to be shared **to a shared module**, kind of like this:

```
Public Sub mySubInSharedModule()
    'event code here
End Sub

Private Sub myEvent()
    Call mySubInSharedModule()
End Sub

Public Sub mySub()
    Call mySubInSharedModule()
End Sub
```

There are numerous articles explaining this further, on this site and others.  To get you started, see [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=private+public+declaration+vba) as well as [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3815547/8112776).

Comment: I have tried with Public also instead of private, but still it shows the compile error