# Calling a sub from another sub compilation error

Tags: vba, excel

I have my main sub named `DXF()` that is called by a button in my excel sheet. `DXF()` calls another sub named `reorganisation(FirstLine, LastLine)`. Now I want `reorganisation` to call another sub named `sens(LastLine)`.
I did it like this in `reorganisation(FirstLine, LastLine)` :

```
Sub reorganisation(FirstLine, LastLine)
[...]
Dim iLine As Integer, Ligne As Integer

With ActiveSheet

Set Temp = Range(.Cells(1000, 1000), .Cells(1000, 1013))

For iLine = FirstLine To LastLine
    [...]
    Ligne = iLine + 1
            Do While Ligne <= LastLine      ''' Organisation par des segments suivant le point de base
                [...]
            Loop
    sens iLine            '''' The error is here
Next iLine
End With
End Sub
```

Everything works well in this sub except where I call `sens`.

Here is the sub `sens`.

```
Sub sens(LastLine)
Dim iLine, Ligne As Integer
With ActiveSheet
    For iLine = 3 To LastLine
        [...]
    Next iLine
End With
End Sub
```

So this gives me the error "Compilation error : sub, function or property needed". I really don't know why it makes this because there is no variable type problem, everything is integer so... If anyone can tell where the problem comes from thanks in advance !

Comment: your code works for me

Comment: Isn't it something like `call sens(iLine)`? I remember something like having to use `call` if the sub or function was in a different module

Comment: @DisplayName try put `sens` and `reorganisation` in different modules, does that affect it?

Comment: @Dan - `Call` is an outdated feature, it is in VBA only to support backwards compatibility.

Comment: Code works fine, there is something else you are not showing, for example variable named sens.

Comment: @DisplayName I guess that's my bad karma... *sigh*

Comment: @Dan, I did that from the beginning. it works

Comment: @Dan that's what Vitaya was trying to say but all of my sub are in the same module. But let me try to put them in different modules

Comment: @BrakNicku omg I think that's my problem. Let me try it !

Comment: You cannot have a variable and a sub with the same name in the same scope.

Comment: @BrakNicku ok that was it. Stupid mistake... Thank you all for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually a really simple mistake. I have a variable that I created a long time ago (so I forgot about it) which was named the same way as my sub. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score -1):

Make the `Sub sens(LastLine)` a public `Sub`. Thus, it would be visible from the worksheet. Like this:

`Public Sub sens(LastLine)`

[What is the difference between Dim, Global, Public, and Private as Modular Field Access Modifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815547/what-is-the-difference-between-dim-global-public-and-private-as-modular-field)

---

This is a simple code that works:

```
Public Sub Reorganisation()    
    Dim iLine As Long
    iLine = 5
    Sens iLine        
End Sub

Public Sub Sens(LastLine As Long)    
    MsgBox "It works"        
End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't work either... Plus all of these subs are in the same module so I imagine I shouldn't get this problem

Comment: Can you write `Sub sens(LastLine as Integer)` instead of `Sub sens(LastLine)`?

Comment: so is using `Public` the correct instead of using `call`? Do you know when this was implemented?

Comment: @JackA - try the "simple code" from my answer and then build up your code around it.

Comment: @Dan - well, it really depends on how you are using VBA. In general, it is advised to avoid `Call`, because it is a bit useless - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479891/what-does-the-call-keyword-do-in-vb6 However, the code would not be broken because of it.

Comment: @Dan - `Public` and `Call` do not have anything to do with each other. They are 
 serving different purposes.