# Public vs Private/Dim in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I could use some help in understanding using Public vs Dim in a module in Excel 2013 VBA.

First I want to say I did find this great post with excellent definitions (see link below), but no examples and I could use some examples of how I could apply the Public Variables to my project.  Also I am a little confused on when I would need to use the Option Private Module; would I need to use that on each module I have or just the module that holds the below code?

[stackoverflow descriptions difference between Public/Private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815547/what-is-the-difference-between-dim-global-public-and-private-as-modular-field)

What I would like to do is set this up in a Standard Mod so I dont have to continue setting variables for worksheets through all of my UserForms that use the same naming convention for Worksheets they reference.

```
Sub PubVar()
Public wb As Workbook
Public wsSI As Worksheet
Public wsRR As Worksheet
Public wsCalcs As Worksheet
Public wsNarr As Worksheet
Public wsEval As Worksheet
Public wsUW As Worksheet
Public wsLVBA As Worksheet

Set wb = Application.ThisWorkbook
Set wsSI = wb.Sheets("SavedInfo")
Set wsCalcs = wb.Sheets("Calcs")
Set wsNarr = wb.Sheets("Narrative")
Set wsEval = wb.Sheets("EvalCL")
Set wsUW = wb.Sheets("UWCL")
Set wsLVBA = wb.Sheets("ListsForVBA")
End Sub
```

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: You can't declare a `Public` variable inside a `Sub`. It goes in the declarations section at the top. But don't do that. Global variables cause ***way*** more problems than they solve.

Comment: Agree with @Comintern - **don't** use global variables.  Why not simply keep that saved in your `personal.xlsb` as a misc. sub (which you won't use!), but keep it there.  Or store in a .txt file somwehere on your computer. 
 Then, when you need it, simple copy/paste the variables to the `Sub` you are actually using.

Comment: @Comintern Unfortunately, VBA has enough coding limitations that you are practically-speaking compelled to use them for many things.  But yes, they should be used as sparingly as possible and with certain restrictions.  I added some paragraphs to my answer to explain this.

Comment: @RBarryYoung That's not strictly true. You can create a property on *anything* to encapsulate a variable, even a standard module.  In my experience the use of global variables is a short-cut that comes from fast and sloppy coding, and the problems that come with using them are almost always avoidable and deserved.

Comment: Thank you all for your guidance and knowledge.  I really appreciate it!  This helped me greatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should only need `Option Private Module` if you are making your own Excel Add-In (*.XLAM file).  It allows a module's `Public` variables to be visible to other modules within the Add-In's own project but keeps them from being visible/callable by other worksheets that use your AddIn.

As for the rest, it's not clear what you are asking.  The question you linked has a good explanation of Public vs Dim/Private.  Private/Dim variables cannot be seen by the VBA code in different Modules, Forms or Classes in the same VBA project.  You use public if you want all of your VBA code to be able to see/call it.  You use private/dim if you want it to only be visible/callable from within it's own module.

But *generally* you want to be judicious with what you make public, both because it can give you too many global names (confusing), can cause problems with duplicate names (problematic, can be addressed with naming standard) and most of all because it can lead to confusing/obscure bugs and horrendous debugging problems (because any public variable change could cause any other code that can see it to behave differently).  And some things are worse than others:

```
Public Subs        OK in a module, but better in a Class
Public Function    Usually fine, especially if its a true function
Public Const       No problem, belongs in modules
Public Variables   Very Bad.  *UNLESS ...*
```

Public variables are the ones that good coders worry about.  They are to be avoided, UNLESS they are what we call "Read-Only Variables".  These are variables that *you set only once, and never change again*.  As long as you follow that rule, they are effectively constants and are OK (though read-only static properties would be better, but VBA has too many limitations in this regard).

Finally If you want to use named variables for all of your worksheets that are visible/useable from all code, but you only have to setup once, that is what `Public` is for, but the declaration ("Public ") needs to be at "*the Module Level*" which means, in a module, *but* outside of any subroutine or function.  Like this:

```
Public wb As Workbook
Public wsSI As Worksheet
Public wsRR As Worksheet
Public wsCalcs As Worksheet
Public wsNarr As Worksheet
Public wsEval As Worksheet
Public wsUW As Worksheet
Public wsLVBA As Worksheet

' sets all of the Worksheet variables
Sub PubVar()

    Set wb = Application.ThisWorkbook
    Set wsSI = wb.Sheets("SavedInfo")
    Set wsCalcs = wb.Sheets("Calcs")
    Set wsNarr = wb.Sheets("Narrative")
    Set wsEval = wb.Sheets("EvalCL")
    Set wsUW = wb.Sheets("UWCL")
    Set wsLVBA = wb.Sheets("ListsForVBA")

End Sub
```

Comment: More specifically, it doesn't just have to be "outside of any subroutine or function", it ***must*** be above the first procedure. Otherwise it makes the grammar impossible to parse because `Private Foo` is an ambiguous fragment after the first procedure.

Comment: Thank you for providing an example of how to set this up.  This now makes more sense to me.  I think i will just stick with declaring the variables as needed instead of using "Public" as it sounds like it could open the doors for a major headache and since I am still relatively new to VBA; I think its best to stick with what works to save me or any users down the road any issues.  Thank you again!

Comment: @ZackE FWIW I downvoted this answer because 1) "VBA has too many limitations" has a tendency to be flatout wrong and make me less receptive about the content of everything else in a post; 2) Recommending public fields is a bad recommendation, especially when 3) no mention is made of `Workheet.CodeName` which is absolutely applicable and preferred here, since the sheets appear to exist at compile-time in `ThisWorkbook`, and 4) the part about `Option Private Module` is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

## Option Private Module

`Option Private Module` should be used in any standard module that doesn't mean to expose its public members to Excel as macros (i.e. `Public Sub` procedures) or User-Defined-Functions (i.e. `Public Function` procedures).

Without this option, a standard module's public parameterless `Sub` procedures appear in Excel's list of available macros, and public `Function` procedures appear in Excel's cell "intellisense" as available worksheet functions.

Note that this merely *hides* a module's members from the macros list: if you type the exact name of a "hidden" procedure, Excel will still run it.

---

## Dim vs Private vs Public

`Dim` is a keyword you use for declaring **local variables**, inside a procedure scope. The keyword is also *legal* for declaring private, module-level variables, but then you might as well use `Private`.

When used for declaring module-level variables, `Private` makes that variable only accessible from within the module it's declared in.

When used for declaring module-level variables, `Public` makes that variable accessible from anything that has access to the module it's declared in - in a standard module, that means the variable is effectively `Global`. In a class (/document/userform/anything else) module, it means the variable holds *instance state* and is accessible from anything that has access to *an instance of* that class. Classes that have a *predeclaredId*, such as `UserForm` classes, all have an instance that's globally accessible: avoid storing instance state in this default instance.

---

## Use Worksheet.CodeName

> ```
> Set wb = Application.ThisWorkbook
> Set wsSI = wb.Sheets("SavedInfo")
> Set wsCalcs = wb.Sheets("Calcs")
> Set wsNarr = wb.Sheets("Narrative")
> Set wsEval = wb.Sheets("EvalCL")
> Set wsUW = wb.Sheets("UWCL")
> Set wsLVBA = wb.Sheets("ListsForVBA")
> ```

`ThisWorkbook` is the workbook you're looking at - the one that contains your VBA code. The `ThisWorkbook` identifier is globally accessible, and `Application.ThisWorkbook` is merely a pointer to that object.

Use `ThisWorkbook` over `Application.ThisWorkbook`, unless you've declared a local variable and named it `ThisWorkbook` - then that local variable would be *shadowing* the global identifier; don't do that. There shouldn't be any reason to need to qualify `ThisWorkbook` with `Application`.

Now, if any of these worksheets exist at compile-time in `ThisWorkbook`, then you don't need any of these variables. Find each sheet in the *Project Explorer* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>), then hit <kbd>F4</kbd> and give its `(Name)` property a meaningful identifier name.

So if you rename `Sheet1` to `SavedInfoSheet`, then you can access `SavedInfoSheet` from anywhere in the code, and you don't ever need to dereference it from the `Workbook.Sheets` (or better, `Workbook.Worksheets`) collection. The reason for this is that VBA automatically creates a global-scope identifier by the name of whatever identifier you put as the `(Name)` property of a `Worksheet` module.

If the sheets don't exist at compile-time (i.e. they're created at run-time), then you don't need these variables either, because the code that created them should already have that reference:

```
Set theNewSheet = theBook.Worksheets.Add
```

Then you can (and should) pass these worksheet object references around, as parameters, as needed.

---

### There is no worksheet.

> *What I would like to do is set this up in a Standard Mod so I dont have to continue setting variables for worksheets through all of my UserForms that use the same naming convention for Worksheets they reference*

Your forms are running the show. The code that fires them looks like this:

```
UserForm1.Show
```

Like any UI, forms are responsible for *collecting user input*, and *showing data to the user*. If you find yourself writing userform code-behind that accesses a dozen worksheets (and/or worse, [makes them *public fields*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51864244/1188513)), you're making your form much, *much* more complicated than it needs to be, and you're **treating a full-fledged object as a mere container for procedures, by making its *default instance* stateful**.

[This article](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) goes in details about how to fix that. [This article](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/05/08/apply-logic-for-userform-dialog/) pushes the concept further and allows back-and-forth communication between the *view* and the *presenter*, and has a download link with a simple example to study (disclaimer: I wrote these articles, and the accompanying example code).

UserForm code done right, looks extremely simple, and is responsible for so little logic, it's boring. In fact, it's not responsible for **any** logic beyond *presentation* - all a UserForm should do, is respond to control events, relay control state to some *model*, and if application logic needs to be executed before the form is closed (e.g. if a command button is clicked but the form should remain open), then it fires an event, and the calling code ("presenter") handles it by triggering the logic that needs to run.

When the dialog is okayed, or when it relays an event to the *presenter*, code *outside* the form's code-behind is executed to to the work: the form never needs to know anything about any worksheet.

Comment: What is the default identifier if I do `const var="123"` outside a function/sub on top of the editor? Is it `private`?

Comment: @Timo the default/implicit access modifier is `Public` in VBA, but IIRC a class module (incl. document modules e.g. workbook/worksheet) cannot legally declare a public const so depending on the type of module you may be forced to prepend an explicit `Private` modifier for it to compile.