# Using array from another sub

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sub (`initialisation`) which contains several arrays. I am then creating another sub (`testSub`) which have to access one of the arrays in `initialisation`. I am unsure how to do this and would appreciate any help you can offer.

Initialisation sub:

```
Sub initialisation()

   init_array = Array("apple", "orange", "car")

   init_array_2 = Array("coconut", "keys", "blue")

End Sub
```

testSub:

```
Sub testSub()

For Each element in init_array 'Does not work currently
   [do stuff]
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to pass the array to the second sub either byRef or byValue `Sub testSub(init_array as Variant)`.

Comment: You coul declare your array as Public, so you can access from anywhere in your project. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/51865287/9199828 and read the section **Dim vs Private vs Public**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass it as parameter like this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub initialisation()

    Dim init_array As Variant, init_array_2 As Variant

    init_array = Array("apple", "orange", "car")
    init_array_2 = Array("coconut", "keys", "blue")
    testSub init_array

End Sub
Sub testSub(init_array As Variant)

    Dim element As Variant

    For Each element In init_array 'Does not work currently
       [do stuff]
    Next

End Sub
```

You should also use `Option Explicit` which will force you to declare all your variables.

Answer (score 2):

You can also define your arrays outside subs:

```
Option Explicit

Dim init_array As Variant, init_array_2 As Variant

Sub initialisation()
    init_array = Array("apple", "orange", "car")
    init_array_2 = Array("coconut", "keys", "blue")
End Sub
Sub testSub()
Dim element As Variant
For Each element In init_array 'Does not work currently
   [do stuff]
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried this solution along with declaring the sub as public but I still can't make this work. I get the same error that init_array is empty.

Comment: Because you need to execute `initialisation` before `testSub` and do it in one `Sub`, otherwise you'll get an error