# How do I elevate a result from within a class method to be visible by another module?

Tags: vba, class

I am trying to write some vba code for Microstation Connect Edition (CAD program similar to Autocad) that permits the use of vba code such as for Excel that makes it possible to create additional/custom functionalities. Since it's a specific vba question, I therefore ask this question on this forum instead of a Microstation forum.

I am trying to achieve something and I have code separated in the modules and in one class modules.

I have some code in my class module that does exactly what I want (see code below, creating a fence which is select method in Microstation in the form of a rectangle), however I would like to use values from m_arrayPoints() from this class module in my other functions in the normal modules (such as x and y values (see picture below). I need these x en y values in creating a query string in the module functions to get results from a database.

I was wondering how I can make the values from m_arrayPoints() useable in the module functions for creating a query string.

In case my question is unclear, please let me know. Then I will try to elaborate better.

Here below the code in the class module

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0
Private Const MODULE_NAME                   As String = "clsPlaceFenceRectangle"
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------
'   Description:
'
'   Example code shows how to create a rectangular shape element and convert it to a fence.
'   In other words, it mimics the operation of MicroStation's Place Fence tool.
'
'   This tool works by prompting the user for two data points.  These are the opposite
'   vertices of a rectangle.  The remaining vertices of the rectangle are calculated.
'   The tool completes when two data points have been harvested.
'
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------
Implements IPrimitiveCommandEvents
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------
'   Class variables
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------
Private m_arrayPoints()                     As Point3d  '   Array of points from user
Private m_nPoints                           As Integer  '   Number of points supplied
Private m_oView                             As View
Private m_bKeepShape                        As Boolean  '   Create shape and add to model
Private m_bCreateFence                      As Boolean  '   Create fence from shape
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Property Let CreateFence(ByVal create As Boolean)
    m_bCreateFence = create
End Property
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Property Let KeepShape(ByVal keep As Boolean)
    m_bKeepShape = keep
End Property
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub IPrimitiveCommandEvents_Cleanup()
End Sub
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------
'   _DataPoint stores Point3d placed by user in our array
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub IPrimitiveCommandEvents_DataPoint(point As Point3d, _
    ByVal oView As View)

    m_nPoints = m_nPoints + 1
    Set m_oView = oView  '   Save view for _Reset event
    '   Move the AccuDraw compass, if enabled, to this data point
    CommandState.AccuDrawHints.SetOrigin point
    
    Debug.Print "m_nPoints=" & CStr(m_nPoints)
    ReDim Preserve m_arrayPoints(0 To m_nPoints - 1)
    
    m_arrayPoints(m_nPoints - 1) = point

    If (1 < m_nPoints) Then
        ShowPrompt "Place opposite point"
    Else
        ShowPrompt "Place first point"
        CommandState.StartDynamics
    End If
    
    If (2 = m_nPoints) Then
        '   Two points is enough to construct a rectangle
        Dim vertices()                      As Point3d
        CalculateRectangleVertices vertices, m_arrayPoints(0), m_arrayPoints(1)
        Dim oShape                          As ShapeElement
        Set oShape = CreateShapeElement1(Nothing, vertices, msdFillModeUseActive)
        '   Add the shape to the active model on request
        If m_bKeepShape Then
            ActiveModelReference.AddElement oShape
        End If
        If m_bCreateFence Then
            CreateFenceFromShapeElement m_oView, oShape
        End If
        m_nPoints = 0
    End If
    
End Sub
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------
'   _Dynamics: draw shape using point array and current cursor location
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub IPrimitiveCommandEvents_Dynamics(point As Point3d, _
        ByVal oView As View, _
        ByVal drawMode As MsdDrawingMode)

    Dim transform                           As Transform3d
    transform = Transform3dFromMatrix3dAndFixedPoint3d(Matrix3dTranspose(oView.rotation), oView.Center)
    
    If (1 = m_nPoints) Then
        '   Two points is enough to construct a rectangle.  We already have one data point,
        '   and the second is provided by this _Dynamics event
        Dim vertices()                      As Point3d
        CalculateRectangleVertices vertices, m_arrayPoints(0), point
        Dim oShape                          As ShapeElement
        Set oShape = CreateShapeElement1(Nothing, vertices, msdFillModeUseActive)
        oShape.Redraw drawMode
    End If
End Sub
' -------------------------------------------------------
'   CalculateRectangleVertices
'   From two diagonally opposed points, calculate the remaining
'   vertices of a rectangle in variable vertices.
'   Vertices is allocated with five points.
' -------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub CalculateRectangleVertices( _
        ByRef vertices() As Point3d, _
        ByRef v1 As Point3d, _
        ByRef v2 As Point3d)
    Const nPoints                           As Long = 5
    ReDim vertices(0 To nPoints - 1) As Point3d
    Dim v                                   As Long
    For v = 0 To nPoints - 1
        vertices(v) = v1
    Next v
    vertices(2) = v2
    vertices(1).X = v2.X
    vertices(3).Y = v2.Y
End Sub
' -------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub IPrimitiveCommandEvents_Keyin(ByVal Keyin As String)

End Sub
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------
'   Reset event not used when creating a rectangle -- 2 points is enough
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub IPrimitiveCommandEvents_Reset()
End Sub
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------
'   Command starts here
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub IPrimitiveCommandEvents_Start()
    ShowCommand "VBA Place Rectangular Fence Example"
    ShowPrompt "Place first point for rectangle"
    '   Clear point array and point count each time we start this command
    Erase m_arrayPoints
    m_nPoints = 0
    Debug.Print "Place Rectangular Fence ..."
End Sub
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your question is too general. I think, a better idea is to edit the question and show your class code and what do you like keep or return from it. Otherwise, I (or somebody else) can show you how a class exemple is written, instantiated and used, but are you sure that you will understand it? If you need help related to a specific class, it is good to show its code and explain the (specific) context of using it...

Comment: @FaneDuru most of the code is quite Microstation specific, but I added the class code in my example if that gives it a bit more context.

Comment: You should declare a `Public` variable on top of the standard module (in the declarations area). `Public myClass as clsPlaceFenceRectangle`. Supposing that its name is the one contained in `MODULE_NAME` constant. Then, in any sub you can use `myClass` variable which must have all the class properties and methods. `myClass.CreateFence True`, `myClass.KeepShape true` etc. `myClass.IPrimitiveCommandEvents_Start`... Anyhow, when you write `myClass.` intellisense will suggest all exposed properties, methods etc.

Comment: @FaneDuru, sorry I am a bit lost what you meant with the sentence **Supposing that its name is the one contained in MODULE_NAME constant.**
The module_name of my code is declared at the top as follows: `Private Const MODULE_NAME                   As String = "modMain"`. Does it mean at the top I have to declare the class follows `Public myClass As clsPlaceFenceRectangle` or as `Public modMain As clsPlaceFenceRectangle` ? 
The following methods are available when I type ** myClass.**: 1) CreateFence and  2)KeepShape, but **myClass.IPrimitiveCommandEvents_Start** is for example not available

Comment: No, you did not understand correctly. Now, I am driving...

Comment: Any application supporting VBA, should have a VBE (Visual Basic for Applications Editor).  Usually, it can be accessed using `Alt + F11`. In its left side part you should see the project explorer (`Ctrl + R` if not being shown). There, each project can have Forms, Standard Modules and Class modules. I was talking about **the class module name, as you can see it there**. Then, you should instantiate the class **from a Standard module**. `Public myClass As new clsPlaceFenceRectangle`, if `clsPlaceFenceRectangle ` is what you see in the project explorer for the specific project...

Comment: Did you copy the class code we can see **from such a class module**, or you opened the `bas` module in a text editor (as Notepad). Usually, the class module name is not seen in the module itself.

Comment: Your question and the eventual answer will be more helpful to the community if you generalized and simplified it. And it would get better, faster answers. e.g. You could just ask, "How do I elevate a result from within a class method to be visible by another module?" Also... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51864001/public-vs-private-dim-in-excel-vba/51864244#51864244

Comment: @FaneDuru oh sorry my picture was not clear. I added another picture. I copied the code directly from the class module into stackoverflow.

Comment: @JohnJoseph Sorry English is not my native language, so I might word some sentences in a weird way. I will change the question title to the one you suggested.