# How to use variable of one function in another function in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I am facing one small problem please help me.

```
sub vari()
dim b as integer
dim c as integer
b=6
c=8
end sub
```

now i want to use b and c in another function .

```
sub calculate()
dim a as integer
a = c+b
end sub
```

I am getting error here

Comment: wat error? which line exactly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I declare a global variable in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722146/how-do-i-declare-a-global-variable-in-vba)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to use the proper [scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29) for your variables. If you want for b and c to be accessible to both vari() and calculate() you need to declare them globally, like so:

```
Public b As Integer
Public c As Integer
sub vari()
....
```