# VBA to transfer a figure from one sheet to another based on matching values other col

Tags: vba, variables

I am working on a spreadsheet which is being used to transfer a product from one location to another. Each day I will have a new list of products that needs sending to another location and I already have a "pre-populated" sheet that has suitable locations listed for where these products can be sent to.

I've already worked out the formula's to use which defines the location these products can be sent to (through index and match formula) but once this has been completed, I'd like to update the "pre-populated" sheet with the quantity I'm sending these locations so that limits can be deducted accordingly.

Essentially, I want to copy the figure from column G in ("Task") into column I in ("interstore transfer") where the two "REF" columns in either sheet match. The "New Limit" column will then automatically populate with the new limit based on the figure input into Column I. Once its finished working its way down the list in the sheet ("Task") then end.

I've had a rough attempt at this, but I'm coming stuck with defining the appropriate variables and how it should update.

**Any ideas to better my approach would be appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

A VBA solution with variables may not be your best approach for this. Variables declared within VBA code usually have a limited lifetime based on their [scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2726329/2658159), so when the code ends the values in the variable will be lost.

Another alternative may be to set aside another cell as a counter. Perhaps a good place for this would be next to the "New Limit" column?

Cell values are retained even when VBA code isn't running. Of course cell values also are saved when the workbook saves, so when you get a new list of products at the beginning of the day you can compare to or edit the previous day's work.

To get started with this, I'd recommend getting familiar with [how to reference cells and ranges](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview.aspx?AssetId=HV805500519990&lcid=1033&NS=EXCEL%2EDEV&Version=12&respos=0&CTT=1&queryid=f2b914ee%2D89a9%2D4560%2D882e%2Df849fd26cc87). And, there is some useful information here on Stack Overflow on [how to reference well in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select/10717999#10717999).