# how to get a subroutine in excel vba to return something?

Tags: excel, vba, function, subroutine

I have the following code in excel vba:

```
Sub main()
    Call Get_Rows_Generic("usersFullOutput.csv", 1)
End Sub
```

in another module i have:

```
Sub Get_Rows_Generic(work_sheet As String, column_num As Integer) 

    Dim wsUsers As Worksheet:             Set wsUsers = Worksheets(work_sheet)
    Dim userRows As Integer:              userRows = wsUsers.Cells(Rows.Count, column_num).End(xlUp).Row

    MsgBox userRows
End Sub
```

How do i access the results of the sub `Get_Rows_Generic` (what is shown in the `MsgBox`) outside of the sub?  i.e. feed the result into another sub or cell...etc.

Comment: If you want a `Sub` to return something make it a `Function`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just make it a function then?

```
Function Get_Rows_Generic(work_sheet As String, column_num As Integer) 

    Dim wsUsers As Worksheet:             Set wsUsers = Worksheets(work_sheet)
    Dim userRows As Integer:              userRows = wsUsers.Cells(Rows.Count, column_num).End(xlUp).Row

    Get_Rows_Generic = userRows
End Sub
```

Then your call could be

```
Sub main()
    Dim result as integer
    result = Get_Rows_Generic("usersFullOutput.csv", 1)
End Sub
```

If you wanted the `result` to be a global variable then I would refer you to this question: [How do I declare a global variable in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722146/how-do-i-declare-a-global-variable-in-vba)

```
Public result as integer
```

Comment: Thanks!  last line of fuction should be `Get_Rows_Generic = userRows`, correct?

Comment: @dwstein Thanks. Yes, you are correct. There should be an equal sign there.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you know that you can convert your Sub into a Function, there is a crude way to achieve what you are trying to do. As VBA/VBScript by default passes the parameters as `ByRef`, you might use this to "return" a value.

```
Sub main()
    Dim userRows as Integer
    userRows = 0
    Call Get_Rows_Generic("usersFullOutput.csv", 1, userRows)
    Msgbox userRows
End Sub

Sub Get_Rows_Generic(work_sheet As String, column_num As Integer, ByRef userRows as Integer) 

    Dim wsUsers As Worksheet:             Set wsUsers = Worksheets(work_sheet)
    Dim userRows As Integer:              userRows = wsUsers.Cells(Rows.Count, column_num).End(xlUp).Row

End Sub
```