# Pass String Variable to different forms within Access Database

Tags: string, forms, ms-access, vba

I have a string variable assigned a value in `Form1`, but wish to use this variable (and the same value) in another form within the database (e.g. `Form2`).

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a [global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722146/how-do-i-declare-a-global-variable-in-vba).

Declare it outside any procedures at the top of `Form1`, like this:

```
Public strYourVariable as String
```

Now, once you have assigned a value to `strYourVariable`, it will be available in other modules and forms.

The global variables will be reset if you:

1. Use "End"
2. Get an unhandled error
3. Edit your VBA code
4. Close Access