# Variable for Excel Columns. Column Assigned to Variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that inserts 2 columns on my current sheet and pastes information from another sheet.

I want to create 2 variables that are assigned to each column that would change the next time I run the macro to paste the information in the next two columns.

```
Columns("BO:BO").Select

Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight

Range("BO2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Feb weekly-wk 2"
Range("BO19").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=VLOOKUP(Comparison!RC2,'Jan16 wk4'!R3C15:R34C24,9,FALSE)"
Range("BO19").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("BO19:BO47"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("BO19:BO47").Select

Columns("BP:BP").Select

Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Range("BP2").Select
Selection.Style = "20% - Accent6"
Range("BP2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Diff"
Range("BP19").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]-RC[-1]"
```

My idea is to set up a variable that I would replace my current "BO" and "BP" code with.

```
Dim X as String, Y as String

X = "BO"

y = "BP"
```

When I run the macro it would change the variable for this example "BO" to "BQ" and "BP" to "BR". Next time I run the macro would change the "BQ" to "BS" and "BR" to "BT".

Comment: then you would use it like this `Columns(x & ":" & x)`

Comment: Alternative to @ScottCraner's suggestion: `Range(Columns(x),Columns(x))`.

Comment: Ah, also, maybe you don't know but you can also refer to a column by it's index (column A = 1, B = 2, etc).  I use this a *ton* in loops. You could use a single variable, say `Dim i as Long`, then do a loop: `For i = 1 to 10 ... Columns(i).Select ... next i`  will loop through columns A through J, and select them.  Or you can use like `Columns(i+1)` where you can't do `Columns("BO"+1)`.

Answer (score 1):

I just cleaned your code a little:

```
Dim ColBO As Integer
Dim ColBP As Integer

Dim StrBO As String
Dim StrBP As String

StrBO = "BO"
StrBP = "BP"

ColBO = ActiveWorkbook.Range(StrBO & 1).Column 'instead of StrBO you could directly write ("BO" & 1)
ColBP = ActiveWorkbook.Range(StrBP & 1).Column 'Then you wouldnt need these two variables

Columns(ColBO).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
'Columns(ColBO).Select   ' Trying to avoid selection but not sure if this works here...
'Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight

Range(1, ColBO).FormulaR1C1 = "Feb weekly-wk 2"
Range(19, ColBO).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(Comparison!RC2,'Jan16 wk4'!R3C15:R34C24,9,FALSE)"
Range(19, ColBO).AutoFill Destination:=Range("BO19:BO47"), Type:=xlFillDefault

Columns(ColBP).Insert Shift:=xlToRight  'Same here as above
Range(2, ColBP).Style = "20% - Accent6"
Range(2, ColBP).FormulaR1C1 = "Diff"
Range(19, ColBP).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]-RC[-1]"
```

For the future: If you can, try to avoid .Select/Selection/.Activate if possible. The code can mostly run without such commands and without activating a cell. ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will be able to test this in Monday. Do I need to change anything for this part?
Range(19, ColBO).AutoFill Destination:=Range("BO19:BO47"), Type:=xlFillDefault

I will want the BO19:BO47 to change as well according to the column

Answer (score 0):

If you are not actually writing BO/BP to the range you are transforming I would go with two ints, stored in a hidden sheet. Read/write each time you run the macro.

This is, in my opinion, the easier solution, other places to go would be  [global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722146/how-do-i-declare-a-global-variable-in-vba) or storing it to a file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use **numeric variables** you can change approach and use `Cells` instead of `Range`:

```
'You can use the rows below to know the column number
Range("BO1").Activate
ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Column 'This way you get the column number into the cell
ColNum = ActiveCell.Column 'This way you get the column number into the variable
'So now you know that BO column number is 67 and you can use
Cells(1, 67) = "OK"
'Or, using variables:
RowNum = 1
ColNum = 67
Cells(RowNum, ColNum) = "You Got It!"
```

This makes you able to loop columns simply using a `for ... next`
If you need to loop from BO to BR you can use

```
For ColNum = 67 To 70
    Cells(1, ColNum) = "OK"
Next ColNum
```

Hope it helps.