# How to output values from cells in Excel to textboxes with date as search parameter

Tags: vba, excel

I have this  data in Excel:
[image: Excel]

I have this user form:
[image: user form]

I click a date in the calendar and then output the data under that date in the first picture. how can i do it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have you tried something? Please post [mcve]

Comment: Use global variables to store the data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722146/how-do-i-declare-a-global-variable-in-vba or write directly to the worksheet

Comment: I honestly can't understand it but I appreciate the help though.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your data is in cell D1 . . .

```
Dim dDate As Date 
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 
    Sheet1.Range("D1").Value = dDate 
End Sub 

Private Sub TextBox1_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean) 

     'Dim dDate As Date
    dDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), Day(Date)) 
    TextBox1.Value = Format(TextBox1.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy") 
    dDate = TextBox1.Value 
End Sub
```