# UDF - Identify if it's a recalculation or first execution

Tags: excel, vba

I want to program a UDF to query a access db. I'm wondering if it's possible to have 2 different Workflows, depending whether it's a first execution or only a recalculation of the UDF.
Ideally I would have a UDF that you can feed the primary key of the db and the UDF presents an overview of possible values of the access db table. If it's a recalculation I don't want to have a userform popup again. Is this possible at all? Can somebody point me in the right direction?
Thx!

**Edit**
An attempt to show some (dummy) code:

```
public function key_from_table(primarykey as string) as string
' Read-out column names from Access table for userform
' Trigger userform with possible column names and let user choose
' readout Chosen column names
key_from_table = Call get_from_db(Primary_key, column_names)
end function

Function get_from_db(Primarykey as string, column_names as string) as string
'call Access db and readout result
end Function
```

If a recalculation is triggered the userform popup comes up again
I'm still new to Excel vba - pls tell me if this is rather stupid :)

Comment: Use a global variable to save the primary key. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722146/how-do-i-declare-a-global-variable-in-vba

Comment: How does your form get triggered?

Comment: @bulbus that only works if I always want the same value from the table

Comment: @Zac My first call is I get all column names from the table, then trigger the form with the possible values - not sure how else to Show this

Comment: A bit confused about the criterion to decide if it is first call or 1+n call. Is `primaryKey` already chosen is one or are all `possible-key-List` is populated? Both of them could be solved by a global variable?

Comment: In case your criterion is `possible-key-List` already populated. You've to show UDF to select `primaryKey` anyways right?

Comment: @bulbus I've added some Explanation - does this clear it up?

Comment: Declare a global Boolean variable (i.e. `bFormTriggered`) in your module where UDF is. When you first trigger the form in your `key_from_table` UDF, set the value of this variable to `TRUE` after you have triggered the form. Just before you trigger the form, check the value of this variable. Only trigger the form if the value of this variable is not `TRUE`

Comment: @Zac that works if I only want to call 1 column. If I need a second column I need to userform to popup again....

Comment: So basically if a recalculation happens or if I drag the UDF down I don't want the userform. If the user Needs a different column from the database - it Needs to come up again

Comment: I think I understand the issue now. In that case, similar approach: declares a global dictionary variable. Just before you trigger the form. check if dictionary already has the column name. If it does, don't trigger the form. If it doesn't, trigger the form and add the column name to dictionary once form is closed

Comment: oh that sounds smart @Zac what are the drawbacks if I don't set the dict to nothing?

Comment: In your case, you shouldn't set the dictionary to nothing because it will lose the value and when you come around the next time. it will trigger the form again. You are not talking about a huge dictionary so it shouldn't impact the performance or memory usage on your PC. Drawback is if you don't clear your objects, you could have memory leaks. To avoid this (again don't think it should affect you), you could set the variable to nothing in `Workbook_BeforeClose`

Comment: oh and it will be impossible to change the selection....@Zac

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `it will be impossible to change the selection`

Comment: @Zac disregard my last cmmt - I meant that if somebody wants to Change the selection, there Needs to be a method to delete the dict-entry but I solved it. The solution is actually quite neat. If you want the stack-points, please submit something as an answer and I'll accept. Thanks for your help

Comment: Answer posted as requested, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declares a global dictionary variable. Just before you trigger the form, check if dictionary already has the column name. If it does, don't trigger the form. If it doesn't, trigger the form and add the column name to dictionary once form is closed. You can clear the variable in `Workbook_BeforeClose` just to be clean

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Public pub_sRecalcCheck As String

Public Function MyTest() As Boolean

    Dim bReCalc As Boolean

    If InStr(1, " " & pub_sRecalcCheck & " ", " " & Application.Caller.Address(External:=True) & " ", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        'This is a brand new calculation
        'Add this cell to the public variable storing where calculations for this UDF have occurred
        bReCalc = False
        pub_sRecalcCheck = WorksheetFunction.Trim(Replace(pub_sRecalcCheck, " " & rCell.Address(External:=True) & " ", " "))

        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        '                                          '
        '    Your code here for new calculation    '
        '                                          '
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    Else
        'This is a recalculation
        bReCalc = True

        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        '                                        '
        '    Your code here for recalcuations    '
        '                                        '
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    End If

    MyTest = bReCalc

End Function
```

EDIT: And just in case the formula gets deleted from the cell, use this in the ThisWorkbook module to clear that cell's address from the RecalcCheck public string variable so that if a new formula is put there it is treated as a new calculation:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rCell As Range

    For Each rCell In Target.Cells
        'Check if cell has been deleted/cleared
        If IsEmpty(rCell) Then
            'Found deleted cell, check if it is stored for the recalc checks
            If InStr(1, " " & pub_sRecalcCheck & " ", " " & rCell.Address(External:=True) & " ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                'It is stored, remove it so that if formula is put back it is treated as a new calculation
                pub_sRecalcCheck = WorksheetFunction.Trim(Replace(pub_sRecalcCheck, " " & rCell.Address(External:=True) & " ", " "))
            End If
        End If

    Next rCell

End Sub
```