# How can i call a variable from another Module in Excel Macro

Tags: excel, variables, module, vba

For example;

I have two Modules, as Module1 and Module2

There are commands as follows in Module1

```
   For i = 2 to 1000
```

And i want to use same "i" variable in Module2.

How can i call the "i" variable from the Module1

Thanx

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722146/how-do-i-declare-a-global-variable-in-vba][1]

Comment: Once you have made it `Public` in Module1, you can reference it within Module2 as `Module1.i`.  (But if you are using `i` as a loop counter, then making it a `Public` variable is a bad, bad, bad idea.)

Answer (score 0):

Hi very simple this way use declare in module1

```vb
Option Explicit
Public i As Integer
```

after that you can access other modules i variable value

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).