# How to take variable from sub in Module and use it in another sub in a UserForm with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, variables

Tried looking this up but I'm still new to VBA and still pretty confused.  I can't figure out how to get the variable from one sub and use it in another sub.

I want to get the variable `ListBox1Items` from `GetListBox1Items` and use it in `cbSave_Click`. I keep getting an error on `Set oNewRow = Selection.ListObject.ListRows.Add(1)`.  I tried `Dim ListBox1Items As String` and `Public ListBox1Items As String` but that doesn't help.

Does the module location of the sub matter?  `GetListBox1Items` is in a Module.  `cbSave_Click` is in a UserForm.

I looked up using Types but it got confusing.

```
Private Sub cbSave_Click()
Dim oNewRow As ListRow
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Creatures").Range("MonsterList")
Set oNewRow = Selection.ListObject.ListRows.Add(1)


With ws

Call GetListBox1

oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 24).Value = Me.StatBox1.Value
oNewRow.Range.Cells(1, 35).Value = ListBox1Items

End With
End Sub
```

and GetListBox1 is

```
Sub GetListBox1()
Dim SelectedItems As String
Dim ListBox1Items As String


With MonsterMaker
    For i = 0 To .ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If .ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
            SelectedItems = SelectedItems & .ListBox1.List(i) & ", "
        End If
    Next i

    ListBox1Items = Left(SelectedItems, Len(SelectedItems) - 2)


End With
End Sub
```

Comment: you will need to make it a global variable. Some pointers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722146/how-do-i-declare-a-global-variable-in-vba

Comment: You could make GetListBox1 a function to return the value of ListBox1Items

Comment: Tried setting global variable in the Userform and in the Module but still getting error at `Set oNewRow = Selection.ListObject.ListRows.Add(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Take the follow abstract example:

Standard module code:

```
Option Explicit
Public ListBoxItems As String 'GLOBAL 

Sub GetListBoxItems()

    Dim selectedItems As String
    Dim i as long

    With ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("ListBox1").Object 'amend as appropriate
        For i = 0 to .ListCount-1
            If .Selected(i) Then 
                selectedItems = selectedItems & .List(i) & ", "
            End If
        Next i
        ListBoxItems = Left$(selectedItems,Len(selectedItems)-2)
    End With

End Sub
```

In UserForm code:

```
Private Sub cbSave_Click()
    Call GetListBoxItems
    Debug.Print ListBoxItems
End Sub
```

Comment: Couldn't get it to work.  Still getting an error at `Set oNewRow = Selection.ListObject.ListRows.Add(1)`

Comment: What does the $ after Left do?  I couldn't find that documented.

Comment: The example was an abstract one to show you how to pass the variable around? i don't know what MonsterMaker is for example. And is the following syntax correct? Selection.ListObject.ListRows.Add(1)

Comment: It is a typed function as you are dealing with strings. The result returned from Left$() is a string, whereas Left() returns a
Variant. If you are dealing with string values, in VBA code, Left$() will be slightly more efficient, as it avoids the overhead/inefficiency associated with the Variant.  From here: https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/196893-difference-between-left-left-function

Comment: MonsterMaker is the name of the Userform.  Both subs work separately so I think the syntax is correct.  It's just when I try to run both from the same button it doesn't work.

Comment: Your new error is unrelated to the question as posted. What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: It says "run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: Guessing some other code is also missing as ws is not declared or set

Comment: I tried deleting everything but calling the `GetListBoxItems` and `Debug.Print` and I still get same error.  I also tried adding `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Creatures")` which is the worksheet it is supposed to add the new row to.

Comment: Without a file to work with i'm afraid this is becoming a complicated debugging session for me.

Comment: No problem.  Thanks for the help.