# How to declare a variable in a sub or function: Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to declare a variable in a sub that can be used by other forms. For Example.

```
Public Class TestClass
    Public Sub MakeVars()
        for i as Int16 = 0 to NumOfVars
            Public Var(i) as String
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then on another file.

```
Var3 = 200
```

I know the naming vars with i doesn't work its just as an example.

Comment: You can't declare a "public" variable in a sub - it needs to be a member of the class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I declare a global variable in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722146/how-do-i-declare-a-global-variable-in-vba)

Comment: Is this VBA or Visual Studio. The two are not the same and the rules are not the same. Please [edit] to remove the inappropriate tag.

Comment: Study the concept of `Scope`.  Where you declare a variable determines its scope - where you can use it.  Your `Public Var` (if it was declared properly) would only exist inside that `For Loop`.  Also look up `Public` because it has nothing to do with scope.  Please read [ask] and take the [Tour]

Answer (score 0):

Approach this as a property of your class, rather than variables. Remember to declare an instance of the class in your main code to make them useable.

A couple of ideas to get you started:

```
Public Class TestClass
    Property Var() as String()
    ReadOnly Property Var(index as Int16) as string ' code returns Var(i)
' Other Class code in here too - including setting up the Var when initialising the Class.
End Class
```