# Return a value from a userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am trying to return a value from a userform to another macro.

Here is an example of a piece of code that I want to return the value `intMonth`:

```
sub comparison()
    UserForm1.Show
end sub
```

then I have the userform code:

```
Private Sub initialize()
    OptionButton1 = False
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    intMonth = 1
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

How do I get the `intMonth` value of `1` back to my original `comparison()` function?

Comment: You could make `intMonth` public, or create a `Public Property`, and then refer to those back in your calling code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722146/how-do-i-declare-a-global-variable-in-vba

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a minimal example, but should help.

[image: screenshot of UserForm]

In the UserForm:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0

Public intMonth As Long    ' <-- the variable that will hold your output

Private Sub initialize()
    OptionButton1 = False
    intMonth = 0
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()  ' OK button
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    intMonth = 1    '<-- set the value corresponding to the selected radio button
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
    intMonth = 2
End Sub
```

In a module or `ThisWorkbook`:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0

Sub comparison()
    UserForm1.Show
    MsgBox CStr(UserForm1.intMonth)   ' <-- retrieve the value
End Sub
```

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Yep - the code as is also doesn't reset the radio buttons if `comparison` is called repeatedly without an editor reset between them :) .  I was trying to keep the answer focused on the OP's stated issue, but agree with your point.  My personal style is `Dim f as UserForm: set f = New UserForm` &c.

Comment: Thank you, i see what i was doing wrong now, i didnt have a variable declared in the userform code for it to return. Can i just confirm, you are saying rather than using UserForm1.Show, i should create an instance of the UserForm in my comparison () sub?

Comment: @MikeHill good news!  Yes, `UserForm1. Show` can cause you problems later, so `comparison` should create an instance.  The second code sample in the article linked above by @MathieuGuindon shows an example.  Happy hacking!

Comment: Yep, i read through it, and i think i actually understand it. Thanks for your help cxw

Answer (score 0):

Another useful way to achieve what you need is to wrap the code in a public function in the userform.

In the UserForm:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0

Private intMonth As Long

Public Function Choose_Option()
    OptionButton1 = False
    intMonth = 0
    Me.show()

    Choose_Option = intMonth 
End sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()  ' OK button
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    intMonth = 1 
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
    intMonth = 2
End Sub
```

Then in module, it is simple as this:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0

Sub comparison()
    MsgBox Userform1.Choose_Option() 
End Sub
```

This way, the function is in charge of showing the userform, prompting the user and returning the value.

If you debug this function, you will see that after Me.Show() is called, the function halts and continue only when the userform is hidden, which is done in the OK button.