# VBA - Opening a workbook and remembering it for other macros

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to create a macro that will:

1. Open a browser window to select a saved workbook (let's call it WB1)
2. In the same macro assign WB1 some form of reference that will allow it to be referenced by other macros

I can achieve step 1 via the following code:

```
Sub Add_New_Survey()
Dim pathString As String
Dim resultWorkbook As Workbook
Dim found As Boolean
pathString = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:="All Files (* . xl*) , *.xl* ")

' check if it's already opened
For Each wb In Workbooks
    If InStr(pathString, wb.Name) > 0 Then
        Set resultWorkbook = wb
        found = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next wb

If Not found Then
    Set resultWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(pathString)
End If
End Sub
```

This will open the workbook. I then need to perform a number of data preparation activities on WB1 which I would like to automate. Is there a way to reference WB1 as I open it from the browser so the following macros know to look on WB1 specifically?

Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your object `resultWorkbook ` is linked to `Workbooks.Open(pathString)`, so as long as you dont unlink it with `Set resultWorkbook = Nothing`, you can reference that workbook always on any sub, (but **declare the variable as Public** first in the module, outside of all subs). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722146/how-do-i-declare-a-global-variable-in-vba

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns - that's a answer, not a comment! (It's also a correct answer, worthy of an upvote or two and a checkmark.)

Comment: Thanks @FreeMan! I'll post it!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. Your object `resultWorkbook` is linked to `Workbooks.Open(pathString)`, so as long as you dont unlink it with `Set resultWorkbook = Nothing`, you can reference that workbook always on any sub, (but declare the variable as Public first in the module, outside of all subs).

To declare a Variable as Public, please read:

> **[How do I declare a global variable in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2722160/9199828)**

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: No problem @Azuremars . If any other doubt or questions arises, please, post a new question. Also, if this answer helped, please, mark it as correct.[Accepting answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)